# Problem in plotting block diagram using blox

Tags: diagrams

I use the sample code below to draw part of a complex block diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\bXInput{U}
\bXBranchx[2]{U}{N1}
\bXBranchx[4]{N1}{N2}
\bXBloc[2]{G1}{$G_1$}{N2}
    \bXLink{U}{G1}
\bXBranchy[4]{N1}{g2}
\bXBloc[-1.5]{G2}{$G_2$}{g2}
    \bXLink{N1}{G2}
\bXBranchy[4]{N2}{g3}
\bXBloc[-1.5]{G3}{$G_3$}{g3}
    \bXLink{N2}{G3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which results in the following output:

[image]

My problem is those small gaps between the horizontal line and the two vertical lines, since I expect the two vertical lines be connected to the horizontal line without any gaps. I don't understand why this happens and how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\bXLink{N1}{G2}` and `\bXLink{N1}{G3}` use `\bXLinkxy{N1}{G2}` and `\bXLinkxy{N1}{G3}` you will get what you need.

[image: linkxy]